# OSM parsing order - Is it sorted?

Tags: java, parsing, openstreetmap

When parsing an OSM file from Open Street Maps to get addresses in a given bounding box, is there any order to how the addresses are listed in the OSM file? E.g. can i expect all of the same street to come in after each other? As in if i have London-street 1 to London-street 55, can I expect these streets to be in order, or at the very least ordered such that all the London-street tags are parsed before a new street begins?

Sorry if it's a dumb question, I've not been able to find sources on this anywhere online, although I admit I might be googling for the wrong keywords. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be directed to OSM.

Answer (score 1):

No, the order of addresses in a typical OSM file is essentially random.

If related addresses happen to be close to each other in the file, that is an accidental result of other circumstances. (For example, several addresses may have been added during the same survey and were therefore assigned similar internal IDs.) None of these can be usefully exploited when parsing an OSM file.

Addresses are also **not**

- unique (several points of interest may be located at the same address)
- of the same element type (addresses can appear on nodes, ways or relations)